# Problems Creating table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table and populate it with records. the new table should be named majorlist and should include the student ID, the student name ( first and last names concatenated with a space in between), major and the age (In whole years) of each student. label the output columns SID, Name, Major, and Age.

```
create table majorlist
 select studentid as 'SID' from students
 select concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as "name" from students
 select major as 'major' from students
 select round((datediff(now(),DOB))/365) as "age" from students;
```

I know each one of these works separately but I cant figure out how to integrate them into a table without getting a error. I try removing the select statments from each one and still that doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table majorlist 
select studentid as 'SID',
       concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as "name", 
       round((datediff(now(),DOB))/365) as "age" 
from students;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer by @juergen d is good. You are creating the table by fetching a single table values `students`.

Then its better to use a single `select` statement for fetching. You can use the query like -

```
 create table majorlist 
   select studentid as 'SID',
   concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as 'name',round((datediff(now(),DOB))/365) as 'age' 
   from students;
```